# Reenable input after submit jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I've a big form named myFrm and I want to disable all enabled input except some of them.

After submit I want to reenable only initial enabled input.

With this piece of code I disable all enabled input except 2 of them:

```
$('[name=myFrm] input:enabled').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('toReenable',true); //I add an attr to flag it
        if ($(this).attr('name')=='my1st'){return;}
        if ($(this).attr('name')=='my2nd'){return;}
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
    $('[name=myFrm]').submit();
```

The form submit only desidered input field but how reenable inital enabled input field? I try without success to add these lines after .submit()

```
$('[name=myFrm] input[toReenable]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('disabled',false);
        $(this).removeAttr('toReenable');
    });
```

The result is that after submit, ALL input field are reenabled, not only toReenabled flagged.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your HTML markup?

Comment: The code as you describe it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fh1eu0k8/ Note that you should really be using a `data` attribute instead of the non-standard `toReenable`